# How to save a XML file in JSP?

Tags: java, xml, jsp, file-io

In my project I need to save XML file in JSP. I'm using Eclipse as IDE and want to save XML file within project so that XML file can be used by Fusioncharts to generate a graph. I cannot give any local path as JSP runs on server.

```
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("C:\\graph.xml"));
```

This won't work in that case, so what can I do in this case?

Comment: Take a look at apache [FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/using.html).

Comment: @Coolbeans: while the question is indeed poorly formulated, based on the code snippet I don't think that the OP's problem is to upload the file from client to server. The OP just want a generic file save location for (temporary) files.

Comment: @BalusC - I see. The save XML file in JSP made me think about fileUpload ... thanks for clarifying :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`File#createTempFile()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29). It's platform independent and in case of a JSP/Servlet webapp it'll be created in the container-managed default temp folder.

```
File file = File.createTempFile("graph", ".xml");
// ...
```

Comment: hey how to access this file? i mean when i had static xml file i used to keep it in web-inf folder and my jsp used to detect it automatically. thanks for reply

Comment: Just pass the `File` or its `FileInputStream` to your Fusioncharts thing?

Comment: <param name="FlashVars"
       value="&dataURL=graph.xml&chartWidth=600&chartHeight=500"> this is written when xml file is ni web-inf folder

Comment: Use a servlet for that so that you have `dataURL=graphServletURL`. In the servlet just write the file to `OutputStream` of the response, or even better, point `StreamResult` to it instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the servlet context to get a web-server independent fiel location in a servlet. I like this way of doing things :

```
public String getCachePath( ServletContext sc, HttpServletRequest request )
{
    //get cache dir from web.xml
    String cacheDir = getInitParameter( "cache.dir");
    //String fileName = File.separator +"tmp"+File.separator +
    String fileName = sc.getRealPath( request.getContextPath() ) + File.separator + "WEB-INF" + File.separator +
    cacheDir + File.separator;
    return fileName; 
}//met
```

And then you can define cache.dir in your web.xml like this :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>server</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>fully qualified name of your class</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cache.dir</param-name>
        <param-value>cache</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Comment: How about when the container is configured to not expand the WAR like as on majority of 3rd party hosts? `getRealPath()` would return `null` then.

Comment: Jetty expands (extracts) WAR by default. Do `<Set name="extractWAR">false</Set>` and try again.

Answer (score 0):

As @BalusC pointed out, my first answer is maybe tied to using jetty  as it expands war.

So, a mechanism that would work whatever server you use would be introspection :

```
 InputSream is = YouClass.getResourceAsStream( "file.xml" );
```

This will always work as long as file.xml is in the same folder (when deployed, in a war or not) as the folder containing the class file YourClass.class.

Eclipse as a special resource folder, enforced in maven, than you can use to put resources and ensure they will be deployed with your class files when you build your projects.

Comment: You're answering how to read the file, not how to save the file. `StreamResult` **writes** the transformed XML to specified target and requires either `File`, `Writer` or `OutputStream`, not an `InputStream`.